# Jmeter Regular Expression Extractor problem

Tags: jmeter, extract

I'm trying to extract a variable but for some reason not successfully.

> 

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/Handsontable/lib/jquery-ui/css/ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui.custom.css">
<script src="/RAMPIT/Scripts/Countable.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/Handsontable/js/highlight/styles/github.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

    var eId = "bda02006-9964-4fbe-bf41-b23ad361e977";
    var eName = "a a";
    var eIndKey = "bda02006-9964-4fbe-bf41-b23ad361e977";
    var eIndColor = "35ffd8";
    var pw_dft_key = '251443dc-feb2-4db1-9a3c-62b4f43763c6';
    var pw_prd_key = '831bb45f-63a5-4ce7-a253-8cc0e17158eb';


    function IamHere(sInd_key, sName) {
        if (typeof (TEAMAPP) == "undefined") {
            return;
        }
        //this one adds the logged in person to his own screen
        TEAMAPP.updateLiveTeamList(sInd_key, sName, "me", eIndColor);
        setTimeout(function () { TEAMAPP.rollCall(); }, 3000)
        setInterval(function () { TEAMAPP.rollCall(); }, 15000)
    }
```

The variable that I want to extract is **pw_prd_key**. I've tried all sort of variations, but non of them successful. When I try my Regex on the Regex tester of Jmeter, it extracts it properly, but for some reason it does not assign it to the varaible.
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuAcG.png)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the Jmeter code you are trying to use.

Comment: any feedback on answer ? If useful you should accept it and upvote. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regex would be:

> pw_prd_key = '([^']+)'

Configuration of [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) is:

[image: REE Configuration]

To further learn jmeter, you may want to read this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops).

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is just fine as it evidenced by [`RegExp Tester` mode of the View Results Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

[image]

I can think of the following possible failure reasons:

- You're referring the variable in a wrong way, you should call it like `${a}` where required
- Your Regular Expression Extractor `Apply to` field doesn't match the response (or variable gets overwritten in one of the sub-results)
- Your Regular Expression Extractor placement is invalid. According to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules) if you want to apply the extractor to one sampler only - you should put it **as a child of particular this sampler**